# Read input without echoing is not working (bash Shell Script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo

"-s" switch is not working bash shell script. It throws error without prompting for the password.

Using: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Am i missing anything?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter password"
read -s password
echo "password:" $password
```

Enter password
test.sh: 4: read: Illegal option -s
password:

Comment: What's the output of `type read`?

Comment: output: read is a shell builtin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the script with `sh`, not `bash` which provides the functionality in question. Either invoke the script directly with bash:

```
bash test.sh
```

Or make the file executable so the interpreter will read your shebang:

```
chmod +x test.sh    # only required once
./test.sh
```

The `.sh` extension is unnecessary unless you are running actual POSIX shell scripts in certain special directories.

Comment: `bash test.sh` works. Thanks. can you pls share the details or some article on difference?

Comment: `sh` is POSIX Shell. It's very old. `bash` is the Bourne Again SHell; a replacement that has evolved into a kind of hybrid command/scripting language. Bash has so many features that it's not fair to compare the two, but there are very old systems which don't have it. We also use `sh` to run boot sequences without loading all the resources that `bash` requires.